# need assistance\ideas on building what is hopefully a simple DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to figure out the DAX to create a new measure in an SSAS Tabular data model.  An example of what I am trying to do is more easily shown than described.  My SSAS Tabular dataset produces the following table.  Cols A and B are from the stores table, Col C is a measure from the Sales table, Col D is a measure from the Products table, and Col E is C/D.  This all works fine.  Data has been mocked up in Excel to protect the innocent, but it is working in Power BI.

[image: This is working]

What I would like to do is add a new measure which calculates the Sales/Product at the state level and have that measure show for each store in that state, as shown below

[image: This is what I want]

Presumably I have to iterate over all rows and calculate the total sales/state and total products sold/state and divide those 2 to get the answer, but can't work out the DAX to get there.  I have tried numerous combinations of

```
calculate(
    sumx(...),
    filter(
        all(...),
        ... 
    )
)
```

to no avail.

Comment: I think it might be something like this (?):
StateTotalsByProductAndDate:=
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN (
            VALUES ( 'Product'[Name] ),
            VALUES ( 'Date'[Date]),
            VALUES ( 'Stores'[State])
        ),
        "Amt", [Sales Amount]
    )

Answer (score 0):

You should use FILTER with ALL to manipulate a context(remove current context);

> MesureSumStateLevel = calculate(SUM('Table'[Amount]),
> FILTER(ALL('StoreStateTab'), 'StoreStateTab'[State] =
> SELECTEDVALUE('StoreStateTab'[State])))

https://dax.guide/filter/

https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/

https://dax.guide/all/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.  I originally tried that and dropped it because I couldn't get it working.  I revisited this morning and solved it.  Here is what I did:

```
 State Ttl = 
     var trxYr = convert(SELECTEDVALUE(dim_date[Year]), INTEGER) //needed because Year is stored as text in the model
     var trxMo = SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Short Month Name])
     var trxState = SELECTEDVALUE(fact_Sales[state])

 Return 
 CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sales[SalesAmt])
     ,all(fact_sales)
     ,year(fact_sales[SaleDATE]) = trxYr
     ,dim_Date[Short Month Name] = trxMo
     ,dim_Stores[state] = trxState
)
```